# Why do I have quotes in CSV File?

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

With this code I want to write header:

```
const string Header = "Name;Date";

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path))
{
   var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer);

   csvWriter.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";

   csvWriter.WriteField(Header);
   csvWriter.NextRecord();
   ...
```

Open file after it:

```
"Name;Date"
```

What I want:

```
Name;Date
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quotes in CSV help to disambiguate when you want to include the delimiter in text that is in an individual field. For example, if I am using regular CSV (with commas as the delimiter), one of the fields might be the address. But if my address is `12 Some Street, Amazing Town`, then I can't store that "as is" - the comma will make any parser think that the address is `12 Some Street`, and the **next** field is `Amazing Town`. So if the value to be stored contains the delimiter, or a newline (for similar reasons, but: next record), quotes are used to tell it what you mean.

In your case, your delimiter is `;` and the value contains `;` - so yes, it needs quotes. I suspect you actually meant to write **two** headers, one `Name`, one `Date`. For example:

```
csvWriter.WriteField("Name");
csvWriter.WriteField("Date");
csvWriter.NextRecord();
```